# Strongly typed wrapper around router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I don't like using `router.navigate` because it's requires to use magical string all over the app. Like

```ts
this.router.navigate(['/user', user.id]);
```

So I would like to create strongly typed wrapper around it:

```ts
export class NavigatorService {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public user(userId: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.router.navigate(['/user', user.id]);
  }
}
```

Of course it should be kept in sync with routing configuration.

What bothers me is usage in templates:

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">
</a>
```

Should I add additional method that returns array?

```ts
export class NavigatorService {

  ...

  public userArr(userId: number): Array<any> {
    return ['/user', user.id];
  }
}

<a [routerLink]="navigator.userArr(user.id)">
</a>
```

Any ideas? May be someone already went down this road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I decided that for simple route I want next service signature:

```js
class NavigatorService {
    user(id: number, matrix: MatrixParams = {}): Navigation { ... }
}
```

where `MatrixParams` is a simple object

```js
interface MatrixParams {
    [index: string]: any
}
```

and `Navigation` is extended array:

```js
interface Navigation extends Array<any> {
    go(extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

`Navigation` can be used both in code and in `routerLink` directive:

```js
    this.navigator.user(1).go();
```

```html
    <a [routerLink]="navigator.user(1)">...</a>
```

To create such object I've used array subclassing as it described [here](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_direct_property_injection):

```js
function navigation(router: Router, ...items: any[]): Navigation {
    let arr: Navigation = <Navigation>[...items];

    arr.go = (extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> => {
        return router.navigate(arr, extras);
    };

    return arr;
}
```

So service implementation would be:

```js
class NavigatorService {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    user(id: number, matrix: MatrixParams = {}): Navigation {
        return navigation(this.router, '/user', id, matrix);
    }
}
```

For more complex routes additional subclasses of navigation can be used:

```js
class NavigatorService {
    ...

    order(id: number, matrix: MatrixParams = {}): OrderNavigation {
        return orderNavigation(this.router, '/order', id, matrix);
    }
}

interface OrderNavigation extends Navigation {
    items(matrix?: MatrixParams): Navigation;
}

function orderNavigation(router: Router, ...items: any[]): OrderNavigation {
    let arr: OrderNavigation = <OrderNavigation>navigation(router, ...items);

    arr.items = (matrix: MatrixParams = {}): Navigation => {
        return navigation(router, ...arr, 'items', matrix);
    };

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create your custom `routerLink` directive that injects your service and uses it to generate the link to be able to use it like

```
[myRouterLink]="32"
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a006c1418a9f4d44f4046976c0ee2824416aa096/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L82-L128

Comment: You mean creating custom directive for each route?

Comment: No, you only create the directive once and put it into a module like `MyRouterModule` to `declarations: [MyRouterLinkDirective]` and exports: [MyRouterLinkDirective]` and then everywhere where you use the directive add the module to `imports: [MyRouterModule]` and `[myRouterLink]="32"` will become a `MyRouterLinkDirective` instance everywhere.

Comment: I meant slightly different thing. What `[myRouterLink]="32"` is equal to? If it equals to `[routerLink]="['/user', 32]"` then I need to create different directive for different routes ('/user', '/client', '/order', etc)

Comment: Yes, if you need different routes, then you need different paths, but I see no difference to `this.router.navigate`, where you also only pass a `userId`. If you provider a different `NavigatorService` on different components, you can specify that part differently in different service instances (just one of a gazillion possiblities) You can also add another `@Input()` to the `MyRouterLinkDirective` to use it like `[myRouterLink]="32" [module]="order"`

Comment: Well, `[myRouterLink]="32" [module]="order" ` is in no way better than `[routerLink]="['/order', 32]`

Comment: I think it's better because you then have `@Input() myRouterLink:number; @Input() module:string;` which does or will in the near future cause type checking to cause errors if the values don't match the types. With `[routerLink]="[any number of values of any kind]"`. But I might have misunderstood what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I don't afraid of using wrong type of value in router link, I am rather worried about refactoring when you change route and need to find all places where you have used it. With `NavigatorService` this task is pretty easy for ts code because compiler will help. But I am not sure how approach it in templates.

Comment: Then I might have misunderstood your question. Angular has language services in the works that should support autocompletion, type checking and refactoring eventually in templates as well.

Comment: Can you give me a link?

Comment: I just saw it mentioned in Github issues. AFAIK it was called language services. There is an isdue and a PR (sorry, just on the phone now)